# Populating drop down list in the PHP variable

Tags: php, html

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $move = '
        <select type = text name="mover">
         <option>select something</option>
          '".while ($dbrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "<option value='".$dbrow['deptname']."'>".$dbrow['deptname']."</option>";}."'
        </select>';

    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$move.'</td></tr>';}
```

I am trying to display dropdown list inside the table. However whenever I apply `while(...)` codes, it displays an error.

shouldn't `HTML` + `'".PHP."'` + `HTML` be the correct way?

Comment: Why the nested `while` loops for a single `select` menu where there are no `optgroup`. Both consume  the same recordset but do you `rewind` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the `select` menu before entering the main loop that builds the table and then rewind the recordset so that the main loop can begin

```
<?php
    $html='<select name="mover">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Please select something';
        
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
        $html.=sprintf('<option>%s',$row['deptname'] );
    }
    
    $html.='</select>';
    $result->data_seek(0);
?>
```

Then build the table.

```
<table>
<?php
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
        printf('<tr><td>%1$s</td><td>%2$s</td></tr>',$row['deptname'],$html);
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate. End your string, start your second while loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $move = '<select name="mover">
    <option>select something</option>';
    while ($dbrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $move .= "<option value='".$dbrow['deptname']."'>".$dbrow['deptname']."</option>";
    }
    $move .= '</select>';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$move.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Removed `type=text` from your `<select>`.

Replaced your `echo`s with `$move .= ...` to add to the `$move` variable.

Be aware that, depending on the number of items in `$row` this would leave your HTML with multiple `<select>`s with the same `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was studying php and html for fun but got stuck into such problem. I will try to figure it out :)

Comment: I understood your point, but  table only shows the first row of data. Perhaps I think it could be due to  `nested while loop`. In PHP, is it not recomend to use `nested loop`?

Comment: Nested loops are ok in PHP, might be because you're looping `$result` in both. Try one of the other answers then

Answer (score 0):

When you use `"` the php is resolved so you just need to escape the html `"`s

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo "<tr><td>$row['name']</td><td><select name=\"mover\"><option value=\"\">select something</option>";
  while ($dbrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      echo "<option value=\"$dbrow['deptname']\">$dbrow['deptname']</option>";
  echo "</select></td></tr>";
}
```